# Block incoming and outgoing calls and texts

Tags: call-screening, sms-blocking

I have a strange request.

Does anyone know of an app that can block incoming AND outgoing calls and texts from certain numbers as well as be password protected (e.g. you need a password to edit, enable, disable or add to the this "blacklist".

Currently I use the auto-reject feature that comes with Android (which isn't password protected) as well as Handcent SMS which blocks notifications of incoming texts (and you can password protect this blacklist). However, you can still read the texts that someone on this blacklist sent if you look them up in your contacts and click Messaging. Neither of these prevent outgoing traffic of any kind.

I would like an app that can block incoming and outgoing calls and texts that can also be password protected. Preferably an app that auto deletes any text messages rather then just blocking the notifications like Handcent does.

If anyone knows of an app that can do any of these features, or know of some open source code that has any of these features (I am a C# developer and could probably pick up on Java pretty quickly) please let me know.

Edit: just to clarify, I don't want to block ALL incoming and outgoing calls/text, only incoming and outgoing calls/texts from certain numbers. I also want to be able to password protect this "blacklist" of numbers.

Comment: That is a strange request. Essentially you just want to kill the phone functions of the device, right? Any reason you didn't get an iPod Touch? Or a wifi-only tablet?

Comment: I don't want to block all incoming and outgoing traffic, only certain phone numbers. And I want to be able to password protect this "blacklist" of numbers

Answer (score 4):

[Miui](http://miuiandroid.com) has a built-in call/message filter, perhaps confusingly called Firewall, since there is also an *actual* internet firewall within the, also confusingly called, Monitor application (a comprehensive call and traffic  *logger* ). Works great though. To password protect it just use the Guard application, also within Miui.