# How to indicate that certain contacts or phone numbers should never be sent outgoing text messages (SMS or MMS)?

Tags: samsung, contacts, sms, mms, sms-blocking

Is there any way in Android or the Samsung Messaging app to mark some contacts or phone numbers as "Do not ever send SMS/MMS to this contact or number"?

I see *incoming* block functionality, but nothing for *outgoing*.

Ideally, I would like certain contacts or phone numbers to simply not be available when selecting recipients from the Messaging app.

(Note that unlike for [this outdated question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12781/block-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-and-texts), it doesn't matter to me whether or not I can receive incoming text messages / MMS from the contacts in question.)

Comment: Samsung has *call barring* to deny outgoing calls as explained in [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220005/131553). Haven't heard of such a feature for SMS

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks. Yes, I took a look at *call barring*, but as you mentioned in your answer, it blocks outgoing calls but unfortunately not SMS / MMS.

Comment: if you use version older than v3.30.3 macrodroid can do actions for outgoing sms, for example trigger airplane mode. not sure if root is required for this